# Clarification about constants in ruby

Tags: ruby, constants

I'm trying to build a rest client and since a lot of is almost the same I thought I'd put the actions into a module and just extend the module to get that set of actions and keep the unique bits separate by defining them as a constant, the same constant but each route has it set differently so the end result is a different URL but the same action.

```
module Common
    def list
        "some_url/#{Route_Name}.json"
    end
end

class Posts
    extend Common
    Route_Name = 'posts'
end

class Comments
    extend Common
    Route_Name = 'comments'
end


Comments.list
#=> "some_url/comments.json"  what I expect to be outputted
```

But it just errors, in this example it would error `uninitialized constant Common::Route_Name`.

How do I get `Route_Name` to be what I expect it to be?

EDIT:

I kind of solved the issue by changing `Route_Name` to `@route_name`, but the problem is that `Route_Name` is constant, it will never change so it doesn't feel right using an instance variable, even if it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby [does constant lookup](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup) first by namespace (roughly: where you've nested them) and then by ancestors (what you've inherited from). Because `list` is declared in `Common`, lookup starts with `Common::Route_Name` and can't go any further.

But, when `list` is called, it's called on `Comments` or `Posts`, giving you access to those via `self`. Instead of leaving Ruby to look for the constant itself, you can use `self::Route_Name` to make lookup start where you want it.

```
module Common
  def list
    "some_url/#{self::Route_Name}.json"
  end
end

class Posts
  extend Common
  Route_Name = 'posts'
end

class Comments
  extend Common
  Route_Name = 'comments'
end

puts Comments.list #=> some_url/comments.json
puts Posts.list    #=> some_url/posts.json
```

Comment: There'll correct but I personally find this to be the most elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar to this, where I've defined several controller actions (index, create, etc..) in a module, then just `include MyModule` in the controller in which I want to use them.

At this point, in my Module I can call `self.controller_name` to get where I actually am coming from.

So instead of trying to set the `Route_Name`, you could derive it with something like `self.controller_name.tableize` or `self.class.tableize`

Answer (score 1):

Use `const_get` instead. It's a method call (compared to lookup by static name). Meaning, that it will start the constant lookup from the bottom of the ancestor hierarchy.

```
module Common
    def list
        "some_url/#{const_get('Route_Name')}.json"
    end
end

class Posts
    extend Common
    Route_Name = 'posts'
end

class Comments
    extend Common
    Route_Name = 'comments'
end


Comments.list # => "some_url/comments.json"
```

@mtamhankar has a good point about deriving routes from class names. Something like this, perhaps (uses `tableize` from ActiveSupport)

```
module Common
    def list
        "some_url/#{name.tableize}.json"
    end
end
```

Comment: good point on `tableize`.. downcase will only work in the two specific examples given.

Answer (score 0):

`@route_name` as you mentioned is an instance variable and will work, but I think what you're actually looking for is `@@route_name` which would make it a class level variable (one per class, not per instance).

Answer (score 0):

A ruby method looks up constants from that method's `owner`, not the receiver or the class of the receiver. When you access a constant, ruby interpreter looks up the constant along `Module.nesting` of the calling module or class.

```
X = 0

module A
  X = 1

  module B
    p Module.nesting  #=> [A::B, A]

    X = 2

    def self.x
      X
    end
  end
end

A::B.x  # Try commenting out any 'X = ?' to see the difference
```

When you call `A::B.x`, ruby tries to find the constant `X` in the namespace `A::B` (i.e. tries to find `A::B::X`), if found, it stops the lookup and returns that value immediately. If not found, then ruby tries to find `X` inside `A`, if still not fount, ruby tries to find `X` inside the top level namespace, which is `Object`.

Since classes and modules have a class/module method `name` which returns the name of the class/module, you can refactor your `Common` module like this:

```
module Common
  def list
    "some_url/#{name.downcase}.json"
  end
end
```

And annihilate all `Route_Name = 'xxx'`